# Radlistbox enable/disable checkbox VB.NET

Tags: telerik, radlistbox

I need help with disabling **only** the checkboxs in RadListBox 
can someone show me how to do it please.(VB.NET)

```
aspx.code:
<telerik:RadListBox ID="rlbNavigateIncidents" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"  CheckBoxes="True" ShowCheckAll="False" Width="239px" Height="315px">
</telerik:RadListBox>
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this server side or client side?

Comment: either way will help me

Comment: When you say "only the checkboxes" are you saying that the little square should be greyed out, but the rest of the text shouldnt?

Comment: I mean it should be read only the user cannot check/uncheck them

Comment: but he can click on the text because I want to use it for redirect to another page.